# how can i pass 2D list to Parameter of function using delegate

Tags: c#, list, delegates

If I have a parameter in function like the following

`List<List<string>> StoredProcedureParameter`

how can I pass 2D list to StoredProcedureParameter

plus I need to do that inline by using delegate and an anonymous method

delegate { return 2D list to StoredProcedureParameter}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom delegates [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
    Func<List<List<string>>, int> delegateToCall = ( myList) => return StoredProcedureParameter(myList)) ;
```

replace `int` by  the required data-type(returned by StoredProcedureParameter) except `void` in `Func` delegate.

or

if `StoredProcedureParameter` returns `void` use `Action` instead.

```
    Action<List<List<string>>> delegateToCall = ( myList) => return StoredProcedureParameter(myList)) ;
```

Comment: why is the parameter name and the function name same?(`StoredProcedureparameter`)

Comment: Based on the question asked by you `I need to do that inline by using delegate and an anonymous method`, my answer seems to be correct because I have used delegate to pass the parameters.

Comment: ok i will explan what i need by another way
i have this fuction 
`
private string StoredProcedureParameter(List<List<string>> StoredProcedureParameter) 
{
return "";
}
`
now i will mearg what you explain to me with what i want and i need to answer me again 

var testmytest = mytest(Func<List<List<string>>, string> delegateToCall = (myList) => return StoredProcedureParameter(myList)));
what is delegateToCall & myList

Comment: what is myList & delegateToCall

Comment: `myList` is the `List` you want to pass as parameter and `delegateToCall` is the name of the delegate.